# How to go back to main function from function void zmianaWierszy(...)?

Tags: c, string

My code is not returning from the function `zamianaWierszy` below:

```
#include"stdio.h"
#include"string.h"
#include"stdlib.h"

void zamianaWierszy(int pierwszy, int drugi,char*tabstat[]) {
    char*pamietajPierwszy;

    size_t rozmiarTab = strlen(*tabstat);
    pamietajPierwszy = tabstat[pierwszy - 1];
    tabstat[pierwszy - 1] = tabstat[drugi - 1];
    tabstat[drugi - 1] = pamietajPierwszy;

    for (int i = 0; i < rozmiarTab; i++) {
        puts(tabstat[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int pierwszy, drugi, pusty;

    char *tabstat[] = {
        (char*)"abcde",
        (char*)"fghi",
        (char*)"jklmn",
        (char*)"koder"
    };
    printf("Podaj wybrane wiersze,które chcesz przestawić:");
    scanf("%d %d", &pierwszy, &drugi);
    zamianaWierszy(pierwszy, drugi, tabstat);

    printf("Podaj po którym wierszu chcesz wstawić pusty wiersz:");
    scanf("%d", &pusty);
    pustyWiersz(pusty, tabstat);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't see the output of the `printf("Podaj po którym wierszu chcesz wstawić pusty wiersz:")` in main.

Comment: Maybe it is only me but I fell like It'd be easier to follow your code and understand the purpose if you translate it to the common language. I had difficulty even to find where `printf("Podaj po którym wierszu chcesz wstawić pusty wiersz:")` is.

Comment: `#include <iostream>` this is C.

Comment: What do you mean by _" then go back to main to print.."_? The function `zamianaWierszy()` once done the control go back to the calling function which is `main()` in your case. There are some problem in your function `zamianaWierszy()`, like the `for` loop is iterating for `rozmiarTab` times which is length of string pointed by first pointer of `char` pointer array `tabstat`. Instead, you should use the number of strings, the pointers of `tabstat` pointing to. Please, specify clearly the problem you are facing.

Comment: My program shows just result from function 'zamianaWierszy()'  and it doesn't go further. I think that function'zmianaWierszy()' works properly, but program stops after  recursion of ZmianaWierszy()' in main.

Comment: Kamil: Yes, this is C, but I included 'system("pause")' and I needed it. Does it disturb in running program properly?

Answer (score 1):

There are many things incorrect with your code, the major ones:

- Check the result of scanf or you may have initialized values for `pierwszy` and `drugi`
- If `pierwszy` is 0 or negative this is going to overwrite the stack frame of the caller function: `tabstat[pierwszy - 1] = ...`
- If `drugi` is 0 or negative this is going to overwrite the stack frame of the caller function: `tabstat[drugi - 1] = ...`
- `rozmiarTab` is going to contain the size of the first string (5) instead of the number of strings in `tabstat` as it is supposed to. So, your for loop is going to access an additional out of range item. However, this is likely to print some garbage or crash but unlikely to affect the return address of your function.

When overwriting the caller stack frame you are likely to overwrite the return address of your function and no one knows where your function could return to... :)

So, you need to check the return value of `scanf` and the values of `pierwszy` and `drugi` and fix the value of `rozmiarTab`.

Comment: Yes , I did it, because I assumed that user will give pierwszy, drugi>0 :)

Comment: Yes ;) Exactly like I wanted - but it doesn't go further and there is a problem.

Comment: I found! I should have given i< rozmiarTab-1 , because i went out of array.

Comment: And there it goes, but I don't know how to insert an empty verse to array in C. I will try sth with malloc funtion . Does it good trade? Sorry for bothering you, but I am a beginner and I really want to learn how to code. Thanks for your attention in advance :)

Comment: I didn't get this: "how to insert an empty verse to array in C". Do you mean you want to add more strings to that `tabstat` array, for example?

Comment: I just want to add empty line. Hmmm, space between strings in my array.

Comment: I don't want even add string, just empty line between strings.

Comment: replace your puts for `printf("%s\n\n", tabstat[i])` . the second `\n` in the format string is your empty line

Comment: Sorry, the user should give a number of indeks of array and after it give empty line ;)

Comment: I mean, user give a 5 then 6 line is empty

Comment: well, whenever you need to insert a empty line just put a printf("\n");

Answer (score 0):

You program is having [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because it is accessing array `tabstat` beyond its size in function `zamianaWierszy()`. *An undefined behavior includes it may execute incorrectly (either crashing or silently generating incorrect results), or it may fortuitously do exactly what the programmer intended.*

Look at this statement of `zamianaWierszy()`:

```
size_t rozmiarTab = strlen(*tabstat);
```

The `*tabstat` is the pointer to first string of array `tabstat` which is string literal `"abcde"`. The `strlen()` will return `5` (size of string without including the terminating null character). The `for` loop iterate for `5` times (`0` to `4`<sup>th</sup> index):

```
for (int i = 0; i < rozmiarTab; i++) {
    puts(tabstat[i]);    // <===========
}
```

Here, the `for` loop end up accessing `tabstat[4]` and the valid index of array `tabstat` is from `0` to `3` (`4` elements). In C, you should very careful when using array in your program and ensure to not to access an array beyond its size.

If you want to iterate to all the elements of `tabstat` in function `zamianaWierszy()`, you have to pass its size as an argument because when you pass array to a function, it decays to pointer.

You should do:

```
void zamianaWierszy(int pierwszy, int drugi, char*tabstat[], size_t tabstat_sz); //declaration

// From the main(), you should call zamianaWierszy() like this
int main() {
    int pierwszy, drugi;

    char *tabstat[] = {
               "abcde",
               "fghi",
               "jklmn",
               "koder"
    };
    ......
    ......
    scanf("%d %d", &pierwszy, &drugi);
    // Make sure to validate the input from user
    ......
    ......
    zamianaWierszy(pierwszy, drugi, tabstat, sizeof(tabstat)/sizeof(tabstat[0]));
    ......
    ......
}

void zamianaWierszy(int pierwszy, int drugi, char*tabstat[], size_t tabstat_sz) {
    char*pamietajPierwszy;

    size_t rozmiarTab = tabstat_sz;   // No need of rozmiarTab variable, you can directly use tabstat_sz
    pamietajPierwszy = tabstat[pierwszy - 1];
    tabstat[pierwszy - 1] = tabstat[drugi - 1];
    tabstat[drugi - 1] = pamietajPierwszy;

    for (int i = 0; i < rozmiarTab; i++) {
        puts(tabstat[i]);
    }
}
```

Also, you should check the `scanf()` return and should validate the user input before using them. Cases like - what if user has given input as `100` and `200` for `pierwszy` and `drugi`. Using them will lead to undefined behavior as the size of `tabstat` is `4`.

Comment: You are a genius!  Dividing sizeof(tabstat)  by sizeof(tabstat[0] secure program from overflow? Could you explain why we have to do this by this way?

Comment: Previously, I just have checked how much is rozmiarTab and it printed 5, but I have, as you mentioned, 4 elements so I just change that: i<rozmiarTab-1 in the loop. And it was also working ;) Thanks for your help a lot ! <3

Comment: @KasiaIks `sizeof(tabstat)/sizeof(tabstat[0])` will give you size of `tabstat` array. If you add some more elements in `tabstat` array, you don't need to bother about its size as `sizeof(tabstat)/sizeof(tabstat[0])` will calculate size based on number of elements in array at that time. If you are still using `size_t rozmiarTab = strlen(*tabstat);`, just try replacing "abcde" with "abcdefghijklmnopqrst" and check whether you program is working fine or not. `strlen(*tabstat)` will give the length of string literal which the first pointer of `tabstat` char pointer array is pointing to.

Comment: Ohhh, I thought that sizeof(tabstat) will be enaugh and I was so suprised why my array is 5 when I have only 4 elements. What did it count additionally?

Comment: btw, thank you for the explanation! I haven't even knew that it works by this way.